# why merging of segments in costly CPU-wise in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have seen that every time I have a high CPU problem with ES, it's always Lucene Merge Thread.

From what I understand, segments are already sorted, so you are just merging two sorted segments every time, à la merge sort's merge process. Why would merging be so costly. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of factors why merging process is costly on IO and CPU:

1. Lucene uses `Skip list` data structure they can be costly to merge, there is a good article about `Skip list merge` [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.17.524&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
2. Couple of parallel merging can happen at the same time.
3. Lucene will need to create a third segment and merge both segment, so you will need enough space for it.

There is a good blog post about segment merging [here](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html).

Comment: Thanks @kaveh for the answer :)